# Is there a tool that converts <style> blocks into inline CSS?

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know a utility which could convert `<style>` blocks into the equivalent `style` attributes in an HTML file?

For example, we have file on input:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.myclass
{
   color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

   <span class="myclass">Some text </span>

</body>
</html>
```

Here’s the desired output file with inline CSS:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <span style="color:red;">Some text </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why would you like to do this? the other way would be more interesting.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Alp, @johnny Because i have many HTML web pages which i want to send by email. But gmail(and maybe other) understand only inline css.

Comment: If it is for mails then write inline styles.

Comment: Really interesting question. I’ve never heard of such a tool, but I’d be interested to know if there is one.

Comment: @Amareswar Ofcourse, i can write inline styles. But i think i could spend a half life more intersting then just copypast thousands lines of code.

Comment: Wouldn't be difficult to do - just a matter of querying the selectors, applying the styles to matched elements inline, throwing away the style block, and saving the current state of the DOM. If I had spare time (which I'll never manage) I'd probably do it...

Comment: I'd probably go for DIY, having some fun with regex finding styles and moving them to the appropriate place (or using some cool html library, i bet there is some linq to html out there) and then adding it as buildstep. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/